# running routine backups from my application

Tags: java, database, backup

i want to run a routine backup of my database from my java application. i'm actually considering a cron job within quartz to fire the backups at the specified time, but i don't know if thats the proper and most efficient way to do it. are there any other ways i can do it? and is there anything i should look out for??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can definitely do this.

If you want to have database backup note that all databases have dedicated backup tools, so an external cron job may suit you as well.